# php nginx config request for this address in a way that will never complete only php not wordpress

Tags: php, nginx, php-5.6

I am the beginner for nginx
I am tryingt to do

**www.mywebsite.com/index.php** to show in the url like **www.mywebsite.com/**
and

**www.mywebsite.com/index.php/user/login** to show in the url like **www.mywebsite.com/user/login**

and I got the error as show in the picture.

Here is my nginx.config

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  4;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
          server_name  www.wcp6288.com;
        root   /var/www/wangou;
        index  index.html index.htmi index.php;
        #charset koi8-r;
        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php$") {
             return 301 $1;
        }

    location / {

       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        # Remove from everywhere index.php
        if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php(/?)(.*)") {
            return 301 $1$3;
     }
    }
    # Remove trailing slash.
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
         rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }
    # Clean Double Slashes
    if ($request_uri ~* "\/\/") {
     rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 permanent;
    }
        #error_page  404              /404.html;
        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
     location = /50x.html {
         root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
  location ~ \.php$ {
       root           /var/www/wangou/;
       fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include        fastcgi_params;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
     }

    }

}
```

[image]

**Thanks you for your helps.**

Answer (score 0):

Should you remove

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

In block:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
   root           /var/www/wangou/;
   fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include        fastcgi_params;
   include fastcgi.conf;
   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Here is my config and it's worked.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name test.dev;
    root "/var/www/html/test/";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/test.dev-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try clear cache your browser? If not fixed i think do not need
`if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php(/?)(.*)") {
            return 301 $1$3;
     }` could you share error_log of Nginx?

Comment: in my log I get

Comment: 16751#0: *25 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.wcp6288.com, request: "GET /whm-server-status HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"

Comment: what is nginx version ?

Comment: nginx version: nginx/1.10.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159848/discussion-between-nguyenvq-and-thet-han).